# TeXstudio macro: toggle between line wrapping

Tags: texstudio

I'd like to make a macro that allows me to change the line wrapping setting in TeXstudio. When editting text, I prefer line wrapping, but for tables, I do not. The ability to quickly switch between them would help.

In my version of TeXstudio, the options are located in `Configure TeXstudio -> Adv. Editor - >Line Wrapping:` where I have four to choose from.

I don't quite know where to start; any insight is appreciated!

Comment: Do you expect the editor to wrap some lines in the file instead of all of them? I don't think this could be done, even with macros.

Comment: No; I'm looking for a very quick way (say pressing CTRL+W to wrap, CTRL+U to unwrap) to change the program settings, for all text and files. I'd change the global settings.

Comment: The answer is here: [link](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/wiki/Scripts#switching-between-no-wrapping-and-soft-wrapping-at-the-window-edge)

Comment: Wonderful - exactly what I was looking for and it opens up many doors to other possibilities.